# SQL developer : connection problem

Tags: 14.04, command-line, sql, sqldeveloper

I installed Oracle SQL Developer in my Ubuntu 14.04.

To set the connection, I have to use two files `tnsname.ora` and `listener.ora`.

How can I find them?

Answer (score 0):

- `tnsnames.ora` (mind the extra s) should be in `$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin/`
- `listener.ora` is also located in `$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin/`.

---

- These 2 files do not have to be there. If not create them yourself using an editor.
- `$ORACLE` is probably installed at `/opt/` or `/var/opt/`. Do an `echo $ORACLE`.

---

If you do not remember where you installed it you can use `locate` to find them with ...

```
locate tnsnames.ora
locate listener.ora
```

`locate` is not real time but based on a database that stores the locations of all files since it was updated. Ubuntu updates this once a week for you. Manual update can be done with ...

```
sudo locatedb
```